# AD Group in SharePoint (2007) Group and Navigation Audiences

Tags: active-directory, groups

I have given an AD group permissions to a SharePoint (Moss 2007) site. Then I added that group as well as some individuals to a SharePoint Group.

I then added a link to the site Navigation (Site Actions > Site Settings > Modify Navigation). For the Audience for the link, I selected the SharePoint Group.

The individuals I added to the SharePoint Group can see the link. The individuals that belong to the AD Group I added to the SharePoint Group can **not** see the link.

If I use the SharePoint Group for security (I give them permissions to a subsite, for example), the members of the AD Group inside the SharePoint Group are able to access the subsite.

Is this expected behavior? Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563696/sharepoint-2007-standard-target-audience-to-ad-group) where a similar issue is reported.

As the post explains, to identify a target audience, you can use one or more of the following:

**SharePoint groups**

**Distribution lists**

**Security groups**

**Global audiences**